# Use Python SDK to upload files to Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: python, api, onedrive

I have a simple task but haven't got a workable solution to make this happen. I'd like to upload two local Excel Workbooks to my OneDrive account, by programming. Simple. I found the following code online to do this, however, the two fields are really confusing: client_secret and client_id. On developer page, I can find application id and application secret, but I don't see client_id and client_secret. I would assume client_id is about my OneDrive Userid, and the secret is some sort of password? But I don't find where I can get a clear description of them.

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/'
client_secret = 'vwIK558@{[pscjkCHCMI68&'
scopes=['wl.signin', 'wl.offline_access', 'onedrive.readwrite']
client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(
    client_id='0000000048201716', 
    scopes=scopes)
auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

You need to create a new App, there will also your secret.

And also check if the host address is configured correctly. 
Look at this picture, have you added `http://localhost:8080/`?
[image: config page]

Comment: Dear Simon, can you elaborate on that? To be specific, I tried this client_id: 00000000481695BB and it worked fine, but this client_id 0000000048201716 doesn't. Is there a place where I can configure Host Address? Thanks.

Comment: Haven't got a chance to try it but I'll let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I took another route. Rather than implementing it myself, I downloaded OneDrive App on my computer and programmed to send files to the local folder and let OneDrive do the work behind the scene. So technically, I still don't know if this would work or not.